# How can I create a PowerShell script that has a custom default imap/smtp server and asks for the user's credentials for setting up Outlook accounts

Tags: powershell, outlook, scripting

I am part of a small IT company that is trying to automate setup for new users creating an Outlook account with our imap/smtp servers. I have tried to research different possible ways to go about this, but every time I try to run a script I get some type error code. My company does not want to use Azure.

I have tried this script:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook"

# Prompt the user for input
$emailAddress = Read-Host "Enter your email address"
$smtpServer = Read-Host "Enter the SMTP server address (default: smtp.example.com)"
$imapServer = Read-Host "Enter the IMAP server address (default: imap.example.com)"
$password = Read-Host "Enter your password" -AsSecureString

# Set default server values if not provided
if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($smtpServer)) {
    $smtpServer = "smtp.example.com"
}
if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($imapServer)) {
    $imapServer = "imap.example.com"
}

# Create a new Outlook Application object
$outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application

# Create a new NameSpace object
$namespace = $outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

# Get the Outlook Accounts collection
$accounts = $namespace.Accounts 

# Set the properties of the Account object
$mailAccount = $namespace.Accounts.Add("$emailAddress", "IMAP/SMTP", $imapServer, $smtpServer)
$mailAccount.SmtpUser = $emailAddress
$mailAccount.SmtpPassword = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto([System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($password))
$mailAccount.SendAndReceiveEnabled = $true
$mailAccount.Save()

# Display a confirmation message
Write-Host "Outlook account has been created with the provided information."
```

and I get these error codes:
Method invocation failed because [System.__ComObject] does not contain a method named 'Add'.
At line:27 char:1

- $mailAccount = $namespace.Accounts.Add("$emailAddress", "IMAP/SMTP",  ...
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Add:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
  ```

The property 'SmtpUser' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At line:28 char:1

- $mailAccount.SmtpUser = $emailAddress
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound
  ```

The property 'SmtpPassword' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At line:29 char:1

- $mailAccount.SmtpPassword = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]: ...
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound
  ```

The property 'SendAndReceiveEnabled' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At line:30 char:1

- $mailAccount.SendAndReceiveEnabled = $true
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound
  ```

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:31 char:1

- $mailAccount.Save()
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
  ```

For this script, I am wanting the user to input their email and password and have the smtp/imap server automatically set as default in order to create a new Outlook user.